# How does the scope of Javascript classes work?

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript file:

```
class Coo {
    constructor() {
    }
}

function foo() {
}
```

Now if I load this into a browser (with a `script` tag), there is now a function `window.foo` defined. However, `window.Coo` is undefined.

So how does the scope of `class` work and how is it different from `function`?

In other words: Where do classes live?

Comment: See the linked questions' answers. Global `class` definitions don't add properties to the global object (which is, loosely speaking, `window` on browsers). This is also true of `let` and `const` declarations. They create globals, but not properties on the global object.

Older-style declarations (`function`, `var`) at global scope *do* create properties on the global object. When the new forms were being added, TC39 (the steering committee for JS) were trying to reduce the exposure of things.